# Grant Anonymous access on SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: anonymous-authentication

I'm using the SharePoint 2013 of the new office 365, and I'm experiencing some troubles to grant access to the anonymous users to the website.

I want to make the SharePoint site public like if it was a public facing website.

I've tried Site permissions under site settings but the option in the ribbon is missing.

I want the two SharePoint sites bellow behaving the same way without the login window.

https://bindspo2013-public.sharepoint.com/
https://bindspo2013.sharepoint.com

Does anyone know how to activate anonymous access?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

How about the Office 365 admin center? Can you access that? 
Then site -> Public Site -> Make Website Online

If it is greyed out in the ribbon, it can be that you havent enabled it yet. You can enable it under:

For Sharepoint 2013 on premise:
Central Administratopn -> Manage Web Applications -> Authentication Providers -> Default -> Enable aynonymous access.

After that, the button will be visible, and you can configure anonymous access.

Comment: The button is not greyed out, it doesn't exist. I belive that your solution is for sharepoint on prem, but I'm using Office 365 e3, I'm not able to access to the central administration

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer for Office 365. I think you can find it in the Office 365 admin center.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using SharePoint Online. SharePoint Online is the cloud-hosted version of SharePoint as opposed to the On-Premise version (SharePoint 2013 and as of now, SharePoint 2016)

It also looks like Microsoft has disabled the "Public Website" (aka anonymous access) feature as of March 2015. So it looks like williamwmy's answer won't work anymore :-(

This article explains it all:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3027254

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Anonymous access for your site. follow the below link:
https://support.cloudshare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200701115-How-to-Enable-Anonymous-Access-to-a-SharePoint-2013-site